# Lost installation cd

Tags: macbook-pro, install

I lost the installation cds from my MBP.

Is that possible get a copy from apple? Or can I use a installation cd from another MBP?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Call (or visit) AppleCare (a genius bar) for a replacement disc to be mailed. If another identical model's media is available, that would work, but the restore media are narrowly made to just work for one or a few models in general.